How to extend sequeulize model with typescript?
Sequelize V° 6.37.3
sequelize-typescript V° 2.1.6
I try to extend a sequelize base model. My layout conatins 2 models: Examination (parent) and ConcreteExamination (child).
examination.ts
import { UUID } from "crypto";
import { CreationOptional, DataTypes, Model, UUIDV4 } from "sequelize";
import { sequelize } from "../db/orm/sequelize";

class Examination extends Model 
{
    declare ID: CreationOptional<UUID>;
    declare probandId: UUID;
    declare examinationClusterId: UUID;
    declare examinationDomainId: UUID;
    declare createdAt: Date;
    declare updatedAt: Date;

    static baseFields = {
        ID: {
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: UUIDV4
        },
        probandId: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID
        },
        examinationClusterId: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID
        },
        examinationDomainId: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID
        },
        updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
        createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    }
}
Examination.init(
    {
        ID: {
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: UUIDV4
        },
        probandId: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID
        },
        examinationClusterId: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID
        },
        examinationDomainId: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID
        },
        updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
        createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
    {
        sequelize
    }
)
export default Examination;

The child should extend the Examination-Model
concrete_examination.ts
import { CreationOptional, DataTypes, UUIDV4 } from "sequelize";
import { sequelize } from "../db/orm/sequelize";
import Examination from "./examination.model";
import { UUID } from "crypto";

class ConcreteExamination extends Examination {
    // extended
    // declare ID: CreationOptional<UUID>;
    // declare probandId: UUID;
    // declare examinationClusterId: UUID;
    // declare examinationDomainId: UUID;
    // declare createdAt: Date;
    // declare updatedAt: Date;

    // concrete
    declare bodySize: Number;;
}

ConcreteExamination.init(
    //super.init(),
    {
        // ID: {
        //     allowNull: false,
        //     primaryKey: true,
        //     type: DataTypes.UUID,
        //     defaultValue: UUIDV4
        // },
        // probandId: {
        //     type: DataTypes.UUID
        // },
        // examinationClusterId: {
        //     type: DataTypes.UUID
        // },
        // examinationDomainId: {
        //     type: DataTypes.UUID
        // },
        bodySize: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
    },
    {
        sequelize
    }

)

export default ConcreteExamination;

A factory create the ConcreteExamination, examination_model.factory.ts:
import { Model } from "sequelize";
import { UUID } from "crypto";
import ConcreteExamination from "../models/examination_anthropometry.model";

export default class ExaminationModelFactory 
{
    static createModel(
        domain: {id: UUID}, 
        cluster: {id: UUID, name: String}) {
        
        let model;    
        switch(cluster.name) {
            case 'concrete':
                model = new ConcreteExamination();
                model.set('examinationClusterId', cluster.id);
                model.set('examinationDomainId', domain.id)
                break;
            default:
                throw new Error('examination cluster not defined');    
        }

        return model;
    }
}

The ConcreteExamination is created, but the parent attributes are missing:
// console.log

ConcreteExamination {
  dataValues: { id: null },
  _previousDataValues: {},
  uniqno: 1,
  _changed: Set(0) {},
  _options: { isNewRecord: true, _schema: null, _schemaDelimiter: '' },
  isNewRecord: true
}

Question:
How to extend a base model with sequelize & typescript?
